# Validation Message for Indexed fields for Loop in MVC 5 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new and currently using Razor MVC 5 and I just want to ask if how to render the Validation message that shows on the indexed EditorFor. Currently Added a Data Annotation `[Required (ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]` and `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` but it shows a validation like `The Char field is required.`

Heres my set of Codes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createform" }))
var cnt = 0;
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @if (Model.AttendeeCount > 0 && Model != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdultCount; i++)
            {
                cnt++;
                <div id="div_@cnt">
                    <div>Adult @i</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName[cnt], new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName[cnt], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "First Name is required" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName[cnt], "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ....
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email[cnt], htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email[cnt], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "Email is required" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email[cnt], "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            } 
        }
    </div>
}
```

Tried over riding the validation by adding  `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "Email is required" } })`

but to no avail still shows the same vaidation error `The Char field is required.` Hope someone can help me with this

Edit: Here is my ModelView

```
[Required (ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name", Prompt = "Attendee Last Name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name", Prompt = "Attendee First Name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "PhoneNumber is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Cell Phone")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: For a start your view will not bind (collection indexers must start a zero and be consecutive). But your `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName[cnt], ...)` etc code makes no sense anyway. What is the model in the view?

Comment: And because `Email` is obviously a `string`, then `model.Email[cnt]` is a `Char` (a character in the `string`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sir Added the Viewmodel code

Comment: Seems you should use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model[cnt].FirstName, ...)`, if the model is an `IEnumerable` (because putting index array to a string property will result a `char`). What is the model type set by `@model` directive inside view?

Comment: No, I mean want is the model in the view - i.e. `@model ????` (it needs to be `@model List<yourModel>`)

Comment: And you do not use `for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdultCount; i++)` - you initialize of `List<T>` containing the number of your model that you want to edit and you return that to the view, then its `for(int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++) { @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FirstName)` etc

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  `@model DB.EventAttendeeModel` heres what i declared at the top of my view

Comment: Are you trying to edit multiple `EventAttendeeModel` in your view - in which case it needs to be `model List<EventAttendeeModel>`

Comment: The model seems not declared as `List` or `IEnumerable`, hence the indexing doesn't makes sense. If you want to use loop for viewmodel properties, put `IEnumerable<EventAttendeeModel>` instead - also the `if` statement should be `@if (Model != null && Model.AttendeeCount > 0)` to avoid NRE.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I forgot to mention that I am just creating a for depending on the number of AdultCount passed by the controller. and posting it after

Comment: Yes I know. Read my previous comments (sorry, but you code simply makes no sense at all). If you are wanting to create say 3 `EventAttendeeModel` items, then you initialize a `List<EventAttendeeModel>` in the GET method, add 3 default instances of `EventAttendeeModel` and pass the list to the view which will have `@model List<EventAttendeeModel>`. And the POST method parameter will also be `List<EventAttendeeModel>` and it will be populated with your 3 edited items